# Int , EditText operation and TabHost error in my app

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-tabhost

I'm stuck during makeing my first simply app in Adroid Studio

1.)

```
Error38, 20) error: bad operand types for binary operator '-'
first type: int
second type: EditText
```

*//Taking number from user*

```
EditText = Age;
Age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inAge);
```

*//Next, Tmax have to, 220 - user input number*

```
Tmax = 220 - Age;
```

And here is this error with number - number from user input.

2.)

```
Error47, 16) error: non-static method setup() cannot be referenced from a static context
```

I have no idea why it is not working propertly.

```
TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabHost);

TabHost.setup(); *//Why is error here?*

TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Calc"); 
tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Calc); 
tabSpec.setIndicator("Calc");
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);

tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Hints"); *//second table, witchout [TabHost.TabSpac] ??*
tabSpec.setContent(R.id.Hints); 
tabSpec.setIndicator("Hints");
tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
```

I have hope, somebody will help me with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering Wiek is your `EditText` object:

1. `Tmax = 220 - Integer.valueOf(Wiek.getText().toString());`
2. `tabHost.setup();`

Explanation:

Wiek is an object, you first need to call getText to get the value that is entered inside of the object.

`TabHost` is the class name and `tabHost` is your instantiated view.